# Dynamically pass custom lookup field value to another custom field

Tags: apex, custom-object

I am new to Salesforce and Salesforce development, and I have an object (Ticket) that is related to another object (Well) via a lookup field for the well ID. I want to pass that well ID to a custom field I have created called WellTicketID. Essentially, I want to populate the WellTicketID field with the lookup field value in the same object without any action required on the user's part. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new custom field on Ticket Object. The type of field will be formula field.
In new field:
1. Select Formula
2. Enter name of field, select return type as 'Text'
3. Then in advanced formula section, In insert field select Well.

Comment: Thanks, Ankush. This worked perfectly!  I set the formula equal to the id and passed the id to WellTicketID so when I called the WellTicketID field, I got the parameters I wanted.